# How can I restart an ansi-term buffer?

Tags: ansi-term, process

I have an open buffer with major mode `ansi-term`, and with scrollback. This buffer has crashed.

I'd like to "recycle" the buffer into a new `ansi-term` such that scrollback is kept. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exited from an bash shell in ansi-term, and this worked for me to resurrect my terminal:

```
M-: (make-term "ansi-term" "/bin/bash") RET
```

(Credits to wgreenhouse on freenode #emacs irc, though he used `zsh`.)